# can someone suggest an idea on printing blanks in an xls file?

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io

still fairly new to matlab, picked up this data analysis code from someone and I had to add in new functions.

for one function I'm calculating the average of every 3 entries in one column and print the result on another column. so it would be something like this

```
1 -1
3 -1
5 =(1+3+5)/3
7 -1
1 -1
1 =(7+1+1)/3
4 -1
```

what I wish to do is to print a blank in the cells that have -1. my first thought was to just assign string values to my results instead of ints. this didn't work because I think there is a line of code in there somewhere that converts everything to ints.

another possible solution is just to reopen the file and loop through all cells replacing any -1's with blank strings, though I'm not sure how to do this, and it's inefficient.

as last resort, I guess I can always tell the user of this xls sheet to use the find/replace function in excel before processing it.

edit: partial code of the save part:

```
data = [data.time, data.avg_time'];
data2 = num2cell(data);
data3 = {'t', 'avg t'};
data = [data3; data2];
xlswrite([filename, '.xls'], data);
```

Comment: can you post the code part where you write the result to the Excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood your question (i thought of replacing NaN's with -1, thanks Amro).

You can use this:

```
A(A(:,2)==-1,2)=NaN
```

where A is the matrix you created first.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: This code replaces **all** instances of -1 in the second column of the matrix A with a NaN. This vastly improves performance if the matrix is long.

Comment: I didn't know I could just assign NaN, I changed all my -1 assignments to NaN and it works now, thanks!

Comment: one problem with replacing values after the fact is if an actual calculated average turned out to be `-1`, it will get replaced as well. My suggestion is to initialize the second column to all `NaN`, and then calculate and place the average values overwriting the existing nans.

Comment: yep, that's what I'm doing. even though it's impossible for a value to be at -1.

Comment: Right Amro, but since he has already calculated the averages (`data.avg_time'`) maybe it's not ideal. Perhaps something fancier like `A(mod(1:length(A),3)'~=0,2)=NaN` will work. That code replaces all the values in the rows of A(:,2) which are not divisible by 3.

Comment: Oh, and you can even combine both conditions (which is unnecessary in this case): `mod(1:length(A),3)'~=0 && A(:,2)==-1`

Comment: well that was just something to be aware of.. You got my vote anyway +1